# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает код?

Tags: html, python, beautiful-soup

Пишу простенькую программу для того, чтобы при активации она выводила *только цифры* из всего массива кода страницы. Всё шло нормально до тех под пока не дошёл до строки:

```
resolte_code = soup.findAll('div', class_='wrap')
```

После неё перестало работать. Но если убрать код ниже этой строки, и выводить на экран тогда выводится вся строка кода вместе с нужными цифрами.

Код у меня выглядит так

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://randstuff.ru/ticket/"

page = requests.get(url)

resolt = []
resolte_code = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

resolte_code = soup.findAll('div', class_='wrap')

for i in range(len(resolte_code)):
    if resolte_code[i].find('div', class_='wrap') is not None:
         resolt.append(resolte_code[i].text)
for i in range(len(resolt):
    print(resolt[i])
```

Comment: _После неё перестало работать_ - подскажите, как понять "перестало работать"? Ваша програма выводит ошибку или так и выводит в консоли: "Я сегодня больше не работаю"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы распарсили страницу по тегу и атрибуту, вы уже получате, то что вам нужно. А в цикле вы снова ищете тот же самый тег, но уже не в странице, а в результатах поиска.

На момент получения resolte_code уже содержит числа в атрибуте text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://randstuff.ru/ticket/"

page = requests.get(url)

resolt = []
resolte_code = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

resolte_code = soup.findAll('div', class_='wrap')

resolt=[int(x.text) for x in resolte_code]


print(resolt)
```